# How to make UIScrollView jump back up after swiping down on it

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I want to make something similar to an `UITableView`.
When you are at the top of the table view when you swipe down and release, the table view jumps back to original position.

In my case I have an scroll view to which I added an view as a contentView (same size) and inside this I have a label.

I have set the scrollview `contentSize` (inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`) to screen width and screen height + 100.
But when I swipe down, nothing moves. Is just like the `contentSize` height is the same as screen or is 0.

Am I missing any steps ? What else should I do ?

Comment: you need to add a content inset your scrollView contentsize must be greater  than your scrollView frame to be scrollable

Comment: @ReinierMelian: but it is, I set the height to be with 100pt greater no ?

Comment: You are using Autolayouts?

Comment: @ReinierMelian: Yes

Comment: then is posible that your content size is don't getting modification, please check that your scrollView content size is what you expect

Comment: @ReinierMelian: yeah, for some reason at runtime the height is equal to the screen height. It doesn't add the +100 part :/

Comment: add a content inset equals to 100 on bottom and let me know must work just fine @Kobe

Comment: I have changed the contentSize inside viewDidAppear and that seems to work. Not sure how ok is this.